# Is Redux internally using context API?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

I had an interview, where the interviewer asked me if redux uses context API internally. Pls provide a detailed description if yes. Thanks

Comment: If I cleared your doubt, please accept my answer: [my_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949588/14886355)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redux doesn't use context api, it's a javascript library for state management. You can use Redux with any application- like (react, angular, vue, svelte, etc). However, for using redux with react applications, you need `react-redux` which is the official react bindings for redux.

`react-redux` uses React's context api to make the redux store accessible to all components. The reason why you need `react-redux` is because, React uses virtual dom - which means you can't manipulate the `DOM` directly. In other libraries like angular, we use the `NgRx` library (For angular).

Answer (score 3):

> Internally, React Redux uses React's "context" feature to make the
> Redux store accessible to deeply nested connected components. As of
> React Redux version 6, this is normally handled by a single default
> context object instance generated by React.createContext(), called
> ReactReduxContext.

[Source](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#understanding-context-usage)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but differently than if you would be doing it by yourself.

If you were to use Context manually, you would usually do *value propagation* - passing the current state value down the tree. This can lead to very inefficient rerendering behaviour. See [this article](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#context-and-rendering-behavior) for a deeper explanation.

React-Redux on the other hand uses context for *dependency injection*. The store is passed down the tree and will never change, never triggering a rerender. All the rest is done by Redux internally, using manual subscriptions. This is much more performant.